# cant access jenkins server from browser

Tags: linux, jenkins, amazon-ec2, automation, cicd

i setup the jenkins server in ubuntu 18 in ec2 aws. this is the bash script i used.

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk -y
sudo apt install maven -y
curl -fsSL https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/jenkins.io-2023.key | sudo tee \
  /usr/share/keyrings/jenkins-keyring.asc > /dev/null
  
echo deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/jenkins-keyring.asc] \
  https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ | sudo tee \
  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list > /dev/null

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jenkins -y
###
```

for security group i set all traffic from anywhere. i am able to ssh to instance and check systemctl status jenkins. i shows running. but when i access jenkins by using pub ip with port :8080. i doest not load.

i  tried removing and adding every rule to security group but nothing helped. also i am using default vpc.
`thank you`

ss are below [inbound rules[image: , jenkins status]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your security group's inbound rules? Do you have any load balancer in front of it? can you also test if the web server is running by curling the Jenkins's web server from inside the EC2? Can you also confirm wether the EC2 instance is running inside a private or public subnet?

Comment: https://paste.pics/9f6388094ca2da6a9bd9087659e4f121

Comment: above mentioned link is for screenshot for inbound rues. thanks

Comment: Bro, please take down the screenshot of your EC2 as you have made your public ip address public which makes you vulnerable to attacks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your Jenkins server is running on a public EC2 instance and you can access it using the following link (I just tested this using both my home PC and mobile phone and I can see the Jenkins initialPassword screen)

[image]

http://YOUR_EC2_PUBLIC_IP:8080/

If you still cant access it from your work machine, then the failure to connect to it may be caused by some network filtering in your work network. Please try to access it on your mobile phone to test this theory.

Comment: thank you so much. can you tell me why is it happening. i mean what settings are there that are causing this issue.

Comment: @MohammadAyan, you will have to speak with your network guy in the company. Using bare IP addresses to host your Jenkins server is dangerous so this network security guys block them to prevent you from doing so.

Comment: @MohammadAyan, if you find this post helpful, you can put a +1 on it and mark it as the answer! This will help guys with similar problems solve their moving forward. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Check Jenkins running

ps aux  | grep jenkins to check Jenkins running

In your case 8080 may be running for different application try to change that port in case 8080 occupied for different application and restart Jenkins it will work for sure!

Answer (score -2):

Hii try to reinstall Jenkins manually

Follow the Following steps to install Jenkins manually.

Installing  Jenkins  in Ubuntu

latest steps

```
wget -q -O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian/jenkins.io.key | sudo apt-key add -

sudo sh -c 'echo deb https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ > \/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list'


sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install jenkins
```

Comment: i tried manually also. service starts up successsfully but when i access public ip with port :8080 on browser it doesnt respond

Comment: Hi @MohammadAyan Could you please mention the steps you followed to install, with a single line it is impossible to understand what went wrong.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).